# Optimize algo to check if records exists, else skip

Tags: python, list, data-structures, time-complexity

Is there a way to can optimize the algo to O(Log n).
Given a List check if records exists between the items. If no records exists then drop the item.

sample code:

```
l1 = [A,B,C,D]

foreach item1 in l1: 
  foreach item2 in l1:
     is_exist=funcCheckRecordsExists(item1,item2)
```

So if no records exists for item (A,B) then no records exists between (B,A) as well. so when I have element items as (B,A) it should skip the function call.
is it possible to reduce the time complexity from `O(n*n)` to `O(log n)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "drop the item"? Should one of the two items be removed from the list?

Comment: I guess you can reduce the inner loop to only test items that come after the first item, but that's still O(n²). What exactly do you want to find? All the combinations of `item1` and `item2` that have a "record", or if there is any such combination, or given one `item1`, find one `item2` so there is a record?

Comment: Would like to find if there are records for any combination. Consider list = [A,B,C,D]. 

So all possible combination are: (A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(B,A),(B,C),(B,D),(C,A),(C,B),(C,D),(D,A),(D,B),(D,C) 

So if no records is found for combination (A,B) then no need to check for (B,A).

Comment: Following tobias_k's suggestion to "only test items that come after the first item", you can write `for i in range(len(l1)): for j in range(i+1, len(l1)): is_exist = func(l1[i], l1[j])` or alternatively `import itertools; for item1,item2 in itertools.combinations(l1, 2): is_exist = func(item1,item2)`. See [the documentation on itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). But it's still O(n²) and certainly not O(log(n)).

Comment: Without knowing that e.g. "records" can be ruled out for (vast) numbers of combinations, there is no way to get this down to O(log n) then. By skipping (B,A), you only reach O(n²/2). If there is more information _when_ there might be a record, you could be able to reduce it to O(n log n) using something like binary search maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your exemple is (n +  1)  x n / 2.

There are 6 commbination of 2 elements in 4.
A formule is :
4! / ( 2! x (6 - 4)! ) = 4x3x2x1 / (2x1 x 2x1) = 4x3 / 2 = 6

And more there are 4 elements (X, X) with X in [A, B, C, D]

The solution is 10 elements for your exemple.

---

If i generalize, we are n!/(2!(n-2)!) + n.

With a combination where 2 elements in n : n!/(2!x(n-2)!)

And n elements with structure (X, X)

---

The algorithme is :

```
list = [A, B, C, D]
for i in list:
    list.pop(i)
    for j in list:
        is_exist=funcCheckRecordsExists(i,j)
```

Best regard,